# VBA print macro to set page in specific manner

Tags: vba, excel, printing

I've been working on a print macro that I think is probably simple. I've tried recording a macro and have been researching for a few hours looking at other peoples code. What I would like is for the macro to:

1) select all cells in the active worksheet

2) set print scale to fit all columns to one page

3) print landscape mode

4) Open print preview (if possible)

5) If #4 is not possible then execute print job.

When I run my current code my excel worksheet gets split into tons of page (checker board style) and then I get an error code. Thanks for reading.

This is my current code:

```
Sub PrintNOPAsheet()'
' PrintNOPAsheet Macro



 Cells.Select
Application.PrintCommunication = False
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
    .PrintTitleRows = ""
    .PrintTitleColumns = ""
End With
Application.PrintCommunication = True
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "$A$1:$H$346"
Application.PrintCommunication = False
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
    .LeftHeader = ""
    .CenterHeader = ""
    .RightHeader = ""
    .LeftFooter = ""
    .CenterFooter = ""
    .RightFooter = ""
    .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
    .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
    .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
    .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
    .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
    .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
    .PrintHeadings = False
    .PrintGridlines = False
    .PrintComments = xlPrintNoComments
    .PrintQuality = 600
    .CenterHorizontally = False
    .CenterVertically = False
    .Orientation = xlLandscape
    .Draft = False
    .PaperSize = xlPaperLetter
    .FirstPageNumber = xlAutomatic
    .Order = xlDownThenOver
    .BlackAndWhite = False
    .Zoom = 100
    .PrintErrors = xlPrintErrorsDisplayed
    .OddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter = False
    .DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = False
    .ScaleWithDocHeaderFooter = True
    .AlignMarginsHeaderFooter = True
    .EvenPage.LeftHeader.Text = ""
    .EvenPage.CenterHeader.Text = ""
    .EvenPage.RightHeader.Text = ""
    .EvenPage.LeftFooter.Text = ""
    .EvenPage.CenterFooter.Text = ""
    .EvenPage.RightFooter.Text = ""
    .FirstPage.LeftHeader.Text = ""
    .FirstPage.CenterHeader.Text = ""
    .FirstPage.RightHeader.Text = ""
    .FirstPage.LeftFooter.Text = ""
    .FirstPage.CenterFooter.Text = ""
    .FirstPage.RightFooter.Text = ""
End With
Application.PrintCommunication = True

Selection.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False
End Sub
```

'

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I usually use, then I made it to match your question. Within the `With` you can add as many of the properties you have from the recorded macro to suit your code.

```
Sub printIt()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Dim rng as Range
Dim printRange as String

Set rng = ws.Range("A1:J11")

''''For Dynamic Ranges'''''
With ws
    Set rng = .Range(.Range("A1"),.Range("J11").End(xlDown))
End With

''''Range from User Highlighted Cells''''
Set rng = Selection
''''This method is not the best way''''

printRange = ws.Name & "!" & rng.Address

With ws.PageSetup
    .PrintArea = printRange
    .Zoom = False
    .FitToPagesWide = 1 'Question 2
    .Orientation = xlLandscape 'Question 3
End With

ws.PrintOut preview:=True 'Question 4

End Sub
```

Comment: Oops I left that part out. I also wanted it to Print Selected Cells.

Comment: I also wanted to say thank you! The code you wrote works perfect other than the fact that I still need to it print selected cells.

Comment: Added in the code to address your issue. Hope this helps!

Comment: How would I make the range dynamic?

Comment: Something like ws.Range(ws.Range("A1"), ws.Range("D1").End(xlDown)). This will make the Range the vertical column and extend down to the last value. This code makes the box from column A to D and then down to the last row of values the Range. To try it out, add "1"s to the cells in column A to D then down to whichever row you want. Then in a module, add this code plus ".Select" to see how excel grabs that Range. Make sure to set the worksheet variable. (Sorry for the long winded reply)